# Invoking pickle results in AttributeError on load() and dump() even though pickle is imported

Tags: python, intellij-idea

This should be very straightforward: i've used `pickle` often in the past. What is wrong this time around?

```
import pickle

with open('data/cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_1','rb') as f:
    dat = pickle.load(f)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'load'
```

The following also fails (if the `load` were commented out)

```
with open ('data/cifar-10-batches-py/small_batch','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(images[0:100],f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'dump'
```

So it seems `pickle` were not being imported properly??

This is in `python 2.7.3`

Comment: Did you by chance create a function named `pickle`? (I know you've answered).

Comment: problem is coming from `cifar.pickle()` that shadows it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pickle` is shadowed by the following (which I did not include in the `OP` because had no idea it were relevant

```
from cifar import *
```

It has

```
# pickle object
# obj: object to pickle
# file_path: file path to store object at in binary cpython blob
def pickle(obj, file_path):
    with open(file_path, "wb") as fo:
        cPickle.dump(obj, fo)
```

It is questionable that `cifar` creates a method called `pickle` this way.. So going forward I need to be more careful on doing

```
 from some_library import *
```